# background merge hit exception during optimization in Luncen.net

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, lucene.net

I am trying to index a 5GB file using lucene.net and getting exception when i try to run the optimize. Below is my code:

```
using (var writer = CreateWriter(analyzer, file.Directory))
            {
                writer.SetRAMBufferSizeMB(32);
                writer.MergeFactor = 1000;
                writer.SetMaxFieldLength(Int32.MaxValue);
                writer.UseCompoundFile = false;

                foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(file.FullName))
                {
                    var columns = line.Split(',');
                    if (columns.Count() > 3)
                    {
                        writer.AddDocument(CreateDocument(columns));
                        totalrecords++;
                        optimizecounter++;
                        if (optimizecounter == 1000000)
                        {                       
                            writer.Commit();
                            optimizecounter = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }

                logger.Info("[ContactFileIndexer]Start Optimizing index.");
                writer.Optimize();  //optimize the index
                writer.Commit();
                writer.Flush(true, true, true);
                writer.Close();
            }
```

Exception raised during the writer.Optimize() and the below is exception.

> An exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in
>   Lucene.Net.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: background merge hit exception: _0:C401311->_0
>   _1:C399551->_0 _2:C199138->_0 _3:C390657->_2 _4:C389889->_2 _5:C219454->_2 _6:C389889->_5 _7:C389889->_5 _8:C220222->_5 _9:C389889->_8 _a:C389889->_8 _b:C220222->_8 _c:C389889->_b _d:C389889->_b _e:C220222->_b _f:C389889->_e _g:C389889->_e _h:C220222->_e _i:C389889->_h _j:C389889->_h _k:C220222->_h _l:C389889->_k _m:C389889->_k _n:C220222->_k _o:C389889->_n _p:C389889->_n _q:C220222->_n _r:C389889->_q _s:C389889->_q _t:C220222->_q _u:C381697->_t _v:C381185->_t _w:C237118->_t _x:C381185->_w _y:C381185->_w _z:C237630->_w _10:C381185->_z _11:C381185->_z _12:C237630->_z _13:C381185->_12 _14:C381185->_12 _15:C237630->_12 _16:C381185->_15 _17:C381185->_15 _18:C237630->_15 _19:C381185->_18 _1a:C381185->_18 _1b:C237630->_18 _1c:C381185->_1b _1d:C381185->_1b _1e:C237630->_1b _1f:C381185->_1e _1g:C381185->_1e _1h:C237630->_1e _1i:C381185->_1h _1j:C381185->_1h _1k:C237630->_1h _1l:C381185->_1k _1m:C381185->_1k _1n:C237630->_1k _1o:C381185->_1n _1p:C381185->_1n _1q:C237630->_1n _1r:C381185->_1q _1s:C381185->_1q _1t:C237630->_1q _1u:C381185->_1t _1v:C381185->_1t _1w:C237630->_1t _1x:C381185->_1w _1y:C381185->_1w _1z:C237630->_1w _20:C381185->_1z _21:C381185->_1z _22:C237630->_1z _23:C381185->_22 _24:C381185->_22 _25:C237630->_22 _26:C381185->_25 _27:C381185->_25 _28:C237630->_25 _29:C381185->_28 _2a:C381185->_28 _2b:C237630->_28 _2c:C381185->_2b _2d:C381185->_2b _2e:C237630->_2b _2f:C381185->_2e _2g:C381185->_2e _2h:C237630->_2e _2i:C381185->_2h _2j:C381185->_2h _2k:C237630->_2h _2l:C381185->_2k _2m:C381185->_2k _2n:C237630->_2k _2o:C381185->_2n _2p:C381185->_2n _2q:C237630->_2n _2r:C381185->_2q _2s:C381185->_2q _2t:C237630->_2q _2u:C381185->_2t _2v:C381185->_2t _2w:C237630->_2t _2x:C381185->_2w _2y:C381185->_2w _2z:C237630->_2w _30:C381185->_2z _31:C381185->_2z _32:C237630->_2z _33:C381185->_32 _34:C381185->_32 _35:C237630->_32 _36:C381185->_35 _37:C381185->_35 _38:C237630->_35 _39:C381185->_38 _3a:C381185->_38 _3b:C237630->_38 _3c:C381185->_3b _3d:C381185->_3b _3e:C237630->_3b _3f:C381185->_3e _3g:C381185->_3e _3h:C237630->_3e _3i:C381185->_3h _3j:C381185->_3h _3k:C237630->_3h _3l:C381185->_3k _3m:C381185->_3k _3n:C237630->_3k _3o:C381185->_3n _3p:C381185->_3n _3q:C237630->_3n _3r:C381185->_3q _3s:C381185->_3q _3t:C237630->_3q _3u:C381185->_3t _3v:C381185->_3t _3w:C237630->_3t _3x:C381185->_3w _3y:C381185->_3w _3z:C237630->_3w _40:C381185->_3z _41:C381185->_3z _42:C237630->_3z _43:C381185->_42 _44:C381185->_42 _45:C237630->_42 _46:C381185->_45 _47:C381185->_45 _48:C237630->_45 _49:C381185->_48 _4a:C381185->_48 _4b:C237630->_48 _4c:C381185->_4b _4d:C381185->_4b _4e:C237630->_4b _4f:C381185->_4e _4g:C381185->_4e _4h:C237630->_4e _4i:C381185->_4h _4j:C381185->_4h _4k:C237630->_4h _4l:C381185->_4k _4m:C381185->_4k _4n:C237630->_4k _4o:C381185->_4n _4p:C381185->_4n _4q:C237630->_4n _4r:C381185->_4q _4s:C381185->_4q _4t:C237630->_4q _4u:C381185->_4t _4v:C381185->_4t _4w:C237630->_4t _4x:C381185->_4w _4y:C381185->_4w _4z:C237630->_4w _50:C381185->_4z _51:C381185->_4z _52:C237630->_4z _53:C381185->_52 _54:C381185->_52 _55:C237630->_52 _56:C381185->_55 _57:C381185->_55 _58:C237630->_55 _59:C381185->_58 _5a:C381185->_58 _5b:C237630->_58 _5c:C381185->_5b _5d:C381185->_5b _5e:C237630->_5b _5f:C381185->_5e _5g:C381185->_5e _5h:C237630->_5e _5i:C381185->_5h _5j:C381185->_5h _5k:C237630->_5h _5l:C381185->_5k _5m:C381185->_5k _5n:C237630->_5k _5o:C381185->_5n _5p:C381185->_5n _5q:C237630->_5n _5r:C381185->_5q _5s:C381185->_5q _5t:C237630->_5q _5u:C381185->_5t _5v:C381185->_5t _5w:C237630->_5t _5x:C381185->_5w _5y:C381185->_5w _5z:C237630->_5w _60:C381185->_5z _61:C381185->_5z _62:C237630->_5z _63:C381185->_62 _64:C381185->_62 _65:C237630->_62 _66:C381185->_65 _67:C381185->_65 _68:C237630->_65 _69:C381185->_68 _6a:C381185->_68 _6b:C237630->_68 _6c:C381185->_6b _6d:C381185->_6b _6e:C237630->_6b _6f:C381185->_6e _6g:C381185->_6e _6h:C237630->_6e _6i:C381185->_6h _6j:C381185->_6h _6k:C237630->_6h _6l:C381185->_6k _6m:C381185->_6k _6n:C237630->_6k _6o:C381185->_6n _6p:C381185->_6n _6q:C237630->_6n _6r:C381185->_6q _6s:C381185->_6q _6t:C237630->_6q _6u:C381185->_6t _6v:C381185->_6t _6w:C237630->_6t _6x:C381185->_6w _6y:C381185->_6w _6z:C237630->_6w _70:C381185->_6z _71:C381185->_6z _72:C237630->_6z _73:C381185->_72 _74:C381185->_72 _75:C237630->_72 _76:C381185->_75 _77:C381185->_75 _78:C237630->_75 _79:C381185->_78 _7a:C381185->_78 _7b:C237630->_78 _7c:C381185->_7b _7d:C381185->_7b _7e:C237630->_7b _7f:C381185->_7e _7g:C381185->_7e _7h:C237630->_7e _7i:C381185->_7h _7j:C381185->_7h _7k:C237630->_7h _7l:C381185->_7k _7m:C381185->_7k _7n:C237630->_7k _7o:C381185->_7n _7p:C381185->_7n _7q:C237630->_7n _7r:C381185->_7q _7s:C381185->_7q _7t:C237630->_7q _7u:C381185->_7t _7v:C381185->_7t _7w:C237630->_7t _7x:C381185->_7w _7y:C381185->_7w _7z:C237630->_7w _80:C381185->_7z _81:C381185->_7z _82:C237630->_7z _83:C381185->_82 _84:C381185->_82 _85:C237630->_82 _86:C381185->_85 _87:C381185->_85 _88:C237630->_85 _89:C381185->_88 _8a:C380417->_88 _8b:C238398->_88 _8c:C376758->_8b _8d:C374785->_8b _8e:C248457->_8b _8f:C372993->_8e _8g:C372993->_8e _8h:C254014->_8e _8i:C372993->_8h _8j:C372993->_8h _8k:C254014->_8h _8l:C372993->_8k _8m:C372993->_8k _8n:C254014->_8k _8o:C372993->_8n _8p:C372993->_8n _8q:C254014->_8n _8r:C372993->_8q _8s:C372993->_8q _8t:C254014->_8q _8u:C372993->_8t _8v:C372993->_8t _8w:C254014->_8t _8x:C372993->_8w _8y:C372993->_8w _8z:C254014->_8w _90:C372993->_8z _91:C372993->_8z _92:C254014->_8z _93:C372993->_92 _94:C372993->_92 _95:C254014->_92 _96:C372993->_95 _97:C372993->_95 _98:C254014->_95 _99:C372993->_98 _9a:C372993->_98 _9b:C254014->_98 _9c:C372993->_9b _9d:C372993->_9b _9e:C254014->_9b _9f:C372993->_9e _9g:C372993->_9e _9h:C254014->_9e _9i:C372993->_9h _9j:C372993->_9h _9k:C254014->_9h _9l:C372993->_9k _9m:C372993->_9k _9n:C254014->_9k _9o:C372993->_9n _9p:C372993->_9n _9q:C254014->_9n _9r:C372993->_9q _9s:C372993->_9q _9t:C254014->_9q _9u:C372993->_9t _9v:C372993->_9t _9w:C254014->_9t _9x:C372993->_9w _9y:C372993->_9w _9z:C254014->_9w _a0:C372993->_9z _a1:C372993->_9z _a2:C254014->_9z _a3:C372993->_a2 _a4:C372993->_a2 _a5:C254014->_a2 _a6:C372993->_a5 _a7:C372993->_a5 _a8:C254014->_a5 _a9:C372993->_a8 _aa:C372993->_a8 _ab:C254014->_a8 _ac:C81626->_ab into _ad [optimize] [mergeDocStores]

Comment: could you try to catch some additional exception information?

Comment: Yes the above was the my exception info. Any suggestions to work with optimization?